# prefix command error

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, npm

When open Terminal I get this error

```
ERROR: Directory [=] does not exist.

The prefix script allows you to manage multiple installations of
a set of software installed on the same machine.  It helps in this
by taking care of the reconfiguration of environment variables
appropriate for each installation.  It is assumed that the
software for each installation is all under a single directory
whose name is assigned to an environment variable called PREFIX.

This arrangement of enabling multiple installations of software
on a single machine is useful at many times.  On a single server,
it can provide for development, test, and production installations
of software.  Alternatively, on development servers,
it allows for multiple development "sandboxes", one for each
developer.  On production servers, it allows for multiple versions
of the production software to be installed.  One might be the currently
running software, one the previous software kept online as a fall-back,
and one a new release of software which is scheduled to be brought
online soon.

There are three usages of the prefix script:

  (1) The interactive usage should be placed as the last line
      of a user's .profile.  The user must be running the
      Korn shell (ksh) or the Bourne Again shell (bash).
      The user is prompted to enter one of the known PREFIX locations,
      specified in the $HOME/.prefixes file or the /etc/prefixes file.
      During configuration, the $PREFIX/.prefixrc file is sourced
      in order to accomplish environment-specific configurations.
  (2) The non-interactive user configuration does not consult
      $HOME/.prefixes or /etc/prefixes or prompt the user, but merely
      configures the environment in accordance with the cmd line argument.
  (3) The batch command usage is mainly for running commands from
      cron or running commands in another environment without changing
      to that environment.

Usage (1): . prefix                     (sets up environment)
      (2): . prefix <prefix>            (non-interactive setup)
      (3): prefix <prefix> <cmd> <args> (runs cmd configured for PREFIX)

/usr/bin/prefix: línea 292: /home/ubuntu-user/npm-global: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand if the problem is npm or environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it happens when you open terminal, it's most likely somehting in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` files. Have you modified them recently? maybe when you installed npm? You'd need to check and fix the file.

Comment: Thanks! I had already checked the .bashrc but I checked again and found the problem, at the end of the file found this line

PATH=$PATH:~/npm-global

But this path doesn't not exists.

I delete it and the problem was solved.

Comment: @DanielHerrera: Maybe you ought to create that directory rather than removing it from PATH.

Comment: I've tried as directory and as an empty file too but doesn't work